# Nest conditional number of AND statements inside an OR with Expression Builder

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

The required query includes a where statement consisting of basic account requirements as well as any possible user selections, with its data as a pair. The code below does not work for more than one selection, i.e. the else {} is incorrect. Is there a way to conditionally build the andX inside the orX inside an andWhere?

```
    $queryBuilder
        ...
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t.code', $queryBuilder->createPositionalParameter($this->code)),
                $queryBuilder->expr()->neq('det.completed', '1')
            )
        );

    if (count($selected) == 0) {
        // no results returned
    }
    else if (count($selected) == 1) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('det.co_id=' . $queryBuilder->createPositionalParameter($co_array[0]) . ' AND det.ct_id=' . $queryBuilder->createPositionalParameter($ct_array[0]));
    }
    else {
        $nestedWhere = $this->db->createQueryBuilder();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($selected); $i++) {
            $nestedWhere->expr()->orX(
                $nestedWhere->expr()->andX(
                    $nestedWhere->expr()->eq('det.co_id', $nestedWhere->createPositionalParameter($co_array[$i])),
                    $nestedWhere->expr()->eq('det.ct_id', $nestedWhere->createPositionalParameter($ct_array[$i]))
                )
            );
        }
        $queryBuilder->andWhere($nestedWhere->expr()); // need dynamic list of orX here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the CompositeExpression class, and my problem appears to be its exact purpose. My solution's code and a link to the Doctrine documentation are below.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.3/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.Expression.CompositeExpression.html

```
// replacing the else {} in thequestion above
else {
    $orX = new CompositeExpression(CompositeExpression::TYPE_OR);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($selected); $i++) {
        $andX = new CompositeExpression(CompositeExpression::TYPE_AND);
        $andX->add('det.co_id = :co' . (string)$i);
        $andX->add('det.ct_id = :ct' . (string)$i);
        $orX->add($andX);
        $queryBuilder
            ->setParameter("co{$i}", $co_array[$i])
            ->setParameter("ct{$i}", $ct_array[$i]);
    }
    $queryBuilder->andWhere($orX);
}
```